# How can I add Delete option to the drop down menu?

Tags: menu

When I right click on a file or folder in Ubuntu 13.10 I only have the option to send it 
to the Trash. I would like to be able to delete it instead. 
How can I add Delete to my choices?
I have searched and found quite a few replies but only found some obscure methods to 
delete files. I have not found out how to add this to the menu.
I would like to just be able to right click and choose "Delete"

Answer (score 2):

nautilus preferences > behavior (open nautilus, click on 'files' in unity panel to get preferences.

or just use gsettings, in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-delete true
```

Comment: Seems like they removed that option in the GUI at or before version 3.18.0. It is no longer there. Also that `gsettings` command gives me: "*No such key 'enable-delete'* " v_v

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my 16.10 to 18.04, and also wanted to just be able to right click and choose "Delete", as I had before.

The answers above gave me some clues, so I did some digging:

`gsettings --help` got me to `gsettings list-schemas`

Then grepping that for `nautilus` I found many related schemas, including `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences`, which was consistent with earlier answers.

Then `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` revealed, among many other keys, `show-delete-permanently`

`gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-delete-permanently` confirmed that it was set to false.

Issuing `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-delete-permanently true` immediately changed the file-menu to include **Delete Permanently** (although it did not get rid of **Move to Trash**)

After this, I'm going to do some more poking around and experimenting. So far, I've found a few other schema / key combinations I want to change, but they are outside the scope of the immediate question.

IM(ns)HO, `gsettings` really needs to offer a way to get a list of all permissible settings for any given schema / key combination. Am I missing something?

If there is a GUI to handle all these variations, I haven't been able to find it;
I would **so** like to see one, but I suppose we should be grateful for what we can have...